# consumiendo API en combo box

Tags: angular, api, webapi, angular13

tengo que consumir esa API , obtengo la respuesta pero no la colocar en un combo box con angular 13, creo que los valores que coloco para desplegar están malos

```
this.http.get<Iresponse>('https://codigo-alfa.cl/Boot/getListCandidatos',
{observe:'response'})




.subscribe((res)=>  {
  const data = <any>res
  console.log(res)
```

Hania probado con esto en el html pero no paso nada

```
<label *ngfor="let item of TokenDecode"> Seleccione  </label>
<select id="lista"></select>
```

Comment: ¿Y por qué iteras `TokenDecode`? ¿Los datos no deberían estar en `res?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios problemas acá:

1. Según el ejemplo la respuesta almacena en `const data`, esta variable no es visible para el template
2. Estas iterando `TokenDecode` que no esta en el ejemplo
3. No estas interpolando el valor que quieres mostrar aparentemente en el label.
4. Me parece que lo que quieres hacer agregar `options` al `select` no al label

Tomando en cuenta todo lo de arriba la solución debería ver se así

```
public data: Iresponse;

..
...
this.http.get<Iresponse>('https://codigo-alfa.cl/Boot/getListCandidatos', { observe:'response' })
   .subscribe((res)=>  {
     this.data = res
}
```

Y en el template

```
<label>Seleccione</label>
<select id="lista">
  <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Seleccione</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of data.<propiedad>" [ngValue]="data.id">. 
    {{data.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Toma en cuenta que tienes que reemplazar `<propiedad>` por la que necesites iterar